# Why does my statement result in a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, stored-procedures

I tried to run this SQL statement in MySQL 5.5 and 5.7.1 but always got error.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE one_off_update_user_info_view_type()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @batchsize BIGINT DEFAULT 1;
  END
//
```

[image]

You could check the script in local MySQL 5.5+ since it does not contain any business logic or inner-company databases. Could anyone tell me why the error arose and how to fix it?

Comment: You may want to review the [rules for MySQL identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html), of which `@batchsize` is an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) in compound-statement syntax to declare a local variable, cursor, condition or handler. However, your variable `@batchsize` is a [*session global* variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) due to the presence of the `@` prefix, and it is an error to attempt to redeclare a global variable.

Change the name of your variable from `@batchsize` to `batchsize`, and then read up on MySQL variables.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `@variable_name` to declare variable. `@` can be used only for session variables.

Change your code to this, it will work

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE one_off_update_user_info_view_type()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE batchsize BIGINT DEFAULT 1;
  END
//
```